# Win7/x64 Skype freeze repeats itself strangely when using Win2003 VMWare guest

Tags: 64-bit, freeze, skype

For some reason, *after resetting Winsock cache with netsh,* weird hangs started to happen.

Each time I try to log into skype from either host machine (Win7 x64) or guest (Win2003 under VMWare x64), the host OR guest gets frozen.

I think this problem is often described  [on the net](http://forums.whatthetech.com/index.php?showtopic=119703), but unfortunately can't just get an idea of: **how does it manage to freeze even a virtual machine** *(CPU virtualization support is enabled)*!?

Upd: hang confirmed with older Skype (3.6)

Upd: both machines had 'Debug' boot option on. I hate the blue trojan and plan to remove this commercial mess out of my workflow - who knows why that code conflicted a debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Both machines had 'Debug' boot option on. It is still unclear why Skype does this, guess it will take a lot of lowlevel debug to get a clue on it.